# Docker Volume Mounting: How to find path in container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a python script that I have placed inside a docker container named "grapher". The python script inside the "grapher" container generates a graph and saves it like so:

```
# CODE ABOVE THIS MAKES PLOT #
plt.draw()
filename = "digraph" + str(self.count) + ".png"
plt.savefig(filename)
```

I want to access these saved figures on my computer, so I am attempting to use "volumes" inside my docker-compose file. The problem is, all the tutorials I find say I need to include the "path in the container". And then the tutorials just magically know what file path to use.

How the heck do I figure out what filepath my container is using?? I've made a bunch of file location guesses based off the tutorials I've found, one of which caused Ubuntu 18.04 to black-screen-of-death (whoops...). I am totally lost. I've included a snippet of my docker-compose.yml file below.

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  # OTHER CONTAINERS ABOVE THIS#
  grapher:
     build: ./Grapher
     depends_on:
       - hmi_pass_thru
     volumes:
      - graph-data:/home/vic/Documents/5ExtraExtraNodes/Grapher
     network_mode: host

volumes:
  graph-data:
networks:
  test_net:
    external: true
```

Please help.

**Edit 1:** My main confusion is that I don't have a file system inside my container. My container is just running the python script. So how do I tell what my "path in container" is?

**Edit 2**: My DockerFile that the "grapher" container is built from:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /home/vic/Documents/5ExtraExtraNodes/Grapher

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python","-u","pcap_grapher3.py"]
```

**Edit 3**: Results of `exec`

```
docker exec -it 5fe4dc4 /bin/bash
root@vic-Capstone:/home/vic/Documents/5ExtraExtraNodes/Grapher# ls -a
.          digraph14.png  digraph21.png  digraph29.png  digraph36.png  digraph43.png  digraph8.png
..         digraph15.png  digraph22.png  digraph3.png   digraph37.png  digraph44.png  digraph9.png
Dockerfile     digraph16.png  digraph23.png  digraph30.png  digraph38.png  digraph45.png  pcap_grapher3.py
digraph1.png   digraph17.png  digraph24.png  digraph31.png  digraph39.png  digraph46.png  requirements.txt
digraph10.png  digraph18.png  digraph25.png  digraph32.png  digraph4.png   digraph47.png
digraph11.png  digraph19.png  digraph26.png  digraph33.png  digraph40.png  digraph5.png
digraph12.png  digraph2.png   digraph27.png  digraph34.png  digraph41.png  digraph6.png
digraph13.png  digraph20.png  digraph28.png  digraph35.png  digraph42.png  digraph7.png
root@vic-Capstone:/home/vic/Documents/5ExtraExtraNodes/Grapher#
```

Comment: Can you clarify what's going on in your example a little bit more? What directory are your files within your `grapher` container getting saved to? With the docker-compose `volumes` syntax, if your program running within the container is saving its files to the directory `/container`, then you can find those files in the directory `/host` on the host if you specify a volume like `/host:/container`. If you have the files saved in a directory with a predictable name, you don't have to worry about guessing what your `grapher` application named its individual files.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to know how docker knows where the **`graph-data`** is? If yes, this path is based on the path where `docker-compose` exists.

Comment: I'm not sure what directory my files inside the 'grapher' container are being saved to. My DockerFile that builds the 'grapher' image is located inside: /home/vic/Documents/5ExtraExtraNodes/Grapher. I thought that by making 'graph-data' I would be making a volume inside 'grapher'?

Comment: How about we try to ```exec``` into a running container and then you can dig in it, run ```ls``` and ```cd``` until you found where your files are

Comment: Edit 3 shows the results of running "exec"

Comment: Since `graph-data` is not a path, Docker will create a volume (see https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and put your data there. You can see where you volume is by running `docker volume inspect graph-data`. All your files (e.g. digraph14.png) should be in the property "Mountpoint"

Comment: The `WORKDIR` line in the Dockerfile specifies the path in the container you're using.  That directory contains your application code, though, so you probably want to mount the volume with the data on to a different directory to avoid overwriting the code (and tell your application where that is, maybe via an environment variable).

Comment: @DavidMaze I am struggling to add two `WORKDIR`'s to my Dockerfile without having the code error. Could you give an example about how to mount to different directories? For example, maybe my python code is in `WORKDIR /app` and my figures are in `WORKDIR /app/graphs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are getting the syntax for volumes backwards.
If you are looking to save files from your container onto you host, bind the volumes as
`host:container`.

You can define whichever path you want inside your container's file system. Then, you save to that location.

Since you copy your files over with

```
COPY . .
```

Your script is copied to the container directory relative to the `WORKDIR`. Mounting this directory will allow you view/edit/save files to your host machine.

From the docs:

```
volumes:
  # Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume
  - /var/lib/mysql

  # Specify an absolute path mapping
  - /opt/data:/var/lib/mysql

  # Path on the host, relative to the Compose file
  - ./cache:/tmp/cache

  # User-relative path
  - ~/configs:/etc/configs/:ro

  # Named volume
  - datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
```

An example Dockerfile which may help explain it better than me:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# all code will be inside this directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# copy all code in present working directory on HOST to /app/. on the CONTAINER
COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

References:

`https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes`

`https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/`

Comment: So I made some changes to try and match your answer. I changed `WORKDIR` to /app in the grapher Dockerfile. And then in Docker-Compose.yml I changed my volumes path to: `/home/vic/Documents/5ExtraExtraNodes/Data:/app` where /home/vic/Documents/5ExtraExtraNodes/Data is a real folder on my host, and /app is hopefully a directory in the container. Now I get the error: **python: can't open file '/app/pcap_grapher3.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**. I do not get this error if I build and run the container outside of compose.

Comment: Try prepending `/app` to your file in the python CMD. To aid in debugging you can also omit the CMD line from your docker file then run the container interactively and look at the files inside it.

Comment: Unfortunately this grapher container is dependent on all my other containers, so if I try and run it alone with `docker run` it errors out because it cannot connect to the other containers. And it errors out faster than I can do the `docker exec` command. Prepending `/app` didn't fix the error.